# how to load distcp checkpoint files?

Tags: training, transformers, python

I have fintuned full aparmeters of mistral 7-b model, and i have used FDSP in HF accelerate

I have a checkpoint which is place in a folder pytorch_model_0, which contains multiple distcp files.

how can i load them and merge them in the model ?

Comment: I have found the solution for llama or you can edit for other models 

you can use this :
 https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama-recipes/blob/main/docs/inference.md#loading-back-fsdp-checkpoints

i have edited some files inside it to load mistral